# Python Facebook SDK sample - ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-python-business-sdk

Following the tutorial from FB on https://developers.facebook.com I ended up downloading a sample file and copying it in a a [github reposotory](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-python-business-sdk) I just cloned (saying that's is the most up to date version of the SDK).

A simple `sudo python setup.py install` as explained in the README to install the dependencies then `python SAMPLE_CODE.py` gives me :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SAMPLE_CODE.py", line 21, in <module>
    from facebookads.adobjects.adaccount import AdAccount
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'facebookads'
```

I have no idea what's wrong with this sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. The import are wrong.

From this :

```
from facebookads.adobjects.adaccount import AdAccount
from facebookads.adobjects.adsinsights import AdsInsights
from facebookads.api import FacebookAdsApi
```

I update it to :

```
from facebook_business.api import FacebookAdsApi
from facebook_business.adobjects.adaccount import AdAccount
```